# Asking AppTrackingTransparency permission for using google analytics , is mandatory?

Tags: swift, ios14, google-analytics-sdk, idfa, apptrackingtransparency

I am using **Google Analytics SDK** in my application.

It uses the demographic area, age and other user informations.

So, Am I need to ask **permission for AppTracking** manually or it was handled in google analytics SDK?

Without AppTracking Permission,Will my future updates get approved by iTunes connect?

Comment: According to Apple, ATT is required for tracking : "Tracking refers to the act of linking user or device data collected from your app with user or device data collected from other companies’ apps, websites, or offline properties for targeted advertising or advertising measurement purposes." developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use . So the question behind is : is the data collected with google analytics used to some kind of targeting?

Comment: used for campaign tracking...!

Comment: I don't track users, we don't use them as ads. Just for analysis. Is it necessary in this situation? Is this related to Privacy Manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES, I need to ask permission for App Tracking Transparency manually. It will not handled by Google Analytics SDK.

Since I am using Google Analytics for campaning tracking, GASDK gets the device IDFA, So the app must need Tracking Permission.

**Note:** If you or your third party framework uses IDFA, It is mandatory to implement app tracking transparency framework. Otherwise Apple will simply reject us.!

Comment: if the user refuses the tracking in the ATT permission popup, the Google Analytics SDK embedded in your app will still collect data and identifiers (but not the IDFA), and may share it with Google for advertising/marketing purposes, which seems not compliant with Apple policy

Comment: If user refuses the tracking permission,IDFA will not shared. so, the irrelevant ads may displays in the users device since targeting is failed here.